# Retrieve a feedback after connection of an user

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

When the user is connected and wishes to consult the feedback section, the user see each feedbacks for eachs users. I would like to know if it's possible to limit this?

For example, if the user is **jeremy@gmail.com**, Jeremy can see only his feedback.

[image]

Here is an idea of my code, I thank you in advance for your help.

```php
    public function index(Request $request)
    {   
        $user = $request->user();

        $feedbacks = Feedback::query()
            ->when($user->hasRole('admin') !== true, function (Builder $query) use ($user) {
                \Auth::user()->load('feedbacks');
                $feedbacksForThisUser = \Auth::user()->feedbacks;
            })
            ->when($request->has('search'), function (Builder $query) use ($request) {
                $query->join('eleves', 'feedbacks.fk_eleve', '=', 'eleves.id')->orderBy('eleves.nom', 'asc')->where('eleves.nom','like','%'.$request->input('search').'%');
             })
            ->paginate(5);

        return view('admin.feedbacks.index', compact('feedbacks'))
            ->with('display_search', $user->hasRole('admin'));
    }
```

Edit

User Model

```
 public function retours()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Retour', 'user_id', 'id');
    }
```

User Feedback

```
public function students(){

    return $this->belongsTo('App\Student', 'fk_student');
    }

    public function feedbacks()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(
            'App\Feedback',
            'App\Student',
            'fk_seance', 
            'fk_student',
            'id', 
            'id' 
        );
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'id', 'user_id');
    }
```

And

```
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->string('instruction', 30);
            $table->text('description', 80);
            $table->integer('fk_student')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('fk_student')->references('id')->on('students');
```

Comment: Add a **return** from callbacks inside `when`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure.  When its a normal user, you can just use `feedbacks = \Auth::user()->feedbacks;`.  This will limit to only the logged in user's feedbacks.

If you want to allow an admin to see all feedbacks, then check for admin, and then provide all.  So, for just the user or admin (without the search code) something like this:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{   
    if(\Auth::user()->hasRole('admin')){
        $feedbacks = Feedback::all();
    }else{
        \Auth::user()->load('feedbacks');
        $feedbacks = \Auth::user()->feedbacks;
    }

    return view('admin.feedbacks.index', compact('feedbacks'));
}
```

You can add the search code into either of the if-blocks, depending on how you want to allow users to see the search.  You can use `when()` on the query, but I'll demonstrate with just `if` to make it easier to understand:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{   
    if(\Auth::user()->hasRole('admin')){
         if($request->has('search'))
              $feedbacks = Feedback::orderBy('nom', 'asc')->where('nom','like','%'.$request->input('search').'%');
         else
             $feedbacks = Feedback::all();
    }else{
         \Auth::user()->load('feedbacks');
         $feedbacks = \Auth::user()->feedbacks;
    }

    return view('admin.feedbacks.index', compact('feedbacks'));
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and your explanations. I have copied your code however, I have no more recording when a user wants to see his feedback. I think the problem is my relationship? I edited my first message. What do you think? Please?

Comment: Yes, I think so.  What is the model - you have a user relationship on that model - so not user... and you have feedbacks, so not feedback... what is the model?   Also - do you need to use `hasManyThrough`?  Thats a very complicated relationship.  Can you use `hasMany` or `belongsToMany` instead?  IE can you add a user_id onto the feedback model to make this simple?  (then `hasMany` on the user model for feedbacks and viola the code in the answer will work perfectly)?

Comment: yes I think my relationship is incorrect. I will change that. Then I will copy your code thanks a lot for your help. ^^

Comment: My pleasure. Try to keep it as simple as possible - user_id FK on the Feedback model and then a simple relationship on the User model will work - much easier :)

Comment: I use the hasManyThrough () because I have to join the tables : student, seance, trainer  via  feedback. It's perhaps bad?

Comment: Not bad, no - but complex.  If you can simplify the logic, I recommend you try to do it with easier relationships until you are more comfortable with the relationships.  Using a join is likely not necessary.  You should be able to have a simple relationship with a pivot (look at Laravel method `withPivot()`) for more info.